# BAT or VBS to purge old files & folders

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I need help tweaking the below code or a new code even to clean up a particular directory on a regular basis.  I have tried a few solutions found online but none of them seem to work right.  I am basically in need of a command to remove files/folders older than X days based on the modified date.  The scripts i have found seem to remove too much.  Most seem to remove the files first then remove any empty directories.  That does not seem to work for me.  Is there perhaps a way to look at the modified date of a folder, and if its old, remove the folder and contents?  The plan is to run this on a weekly basis via task scheduler.

I will see if i can explain my data:

*My Data:*

Mainfolder

Subfolder1

SubSubFolder1.1 - Old Folder containing old files

SubSubFolder1.2 - Old Folder containing old files

SubSubFolder1.3 - New Folder containing new files

Subfolder2

SubSubFolder2.1 - Old Folder containing old files

Subfolder3

SubSubFolder3.1 - New Folder containing new files

*The result of the script should look like this with only the following folders\files remaining:*

Mainfolder

Subfolder1

SubSubFolder1.3 - New Folder containing new files

Subfolder2 - DELETED

Subfolder3

SubSubFolder3.1 - New Folder containing new files

Below is the code i found online and have been trying to modify but have yet to get it to work properly.  I have tried tweaking it but no luck getting the results i am trying to achieve.  It keeps removing too much data, or if tweaked by commenting out some lines, it does not remove enough.

```
Const strPath = "C:\Temp"
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call Search (strPath)

' Comment out below line if you'd like to use this script in windows schedule task
WScript.Echo"Done."

Sub Search(str)
Dim objFolder, objSubFolder, objFile
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(str)
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

    ' Use DateLastModified for modified date of a file
    If objFile.DateCreated < (Now() - 5) Then
        objFile.Delete(True)
    End If

Next
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    Search(objSubFolder.Path)

    ' Files have been deleted, now see if the folder is empty.
    If (objSubFolder.Files.Count = 0) Then
        objSubFolder.Delete True
    End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `FORFILES` command?

```
REM This will print the files which have not been modified in the last 90 days.
FORFILES /P "C:\Dir\To\Clean" /S /D -90 /C "CMD /C ECHO @path"

REM This will _delete_ the files which have not been modified in the last 90 days.
FORFILES /P "C:\Dir\To\Clean" /S /D -90 /C "CMD /C DEL /F @path"
```

Comment: I have tried that one but i need to also remove the directories those files were in.  But i do not need to do a mass look for empty directories and remove them all if empty.

Comment: Since it appears a directory is all or nothing, why not purge the returned directories included in the results (this would include the obsolete files by default): `FORFILES /P "C:\Dir\To\Clean" /S /D -90 /C "CMD /C IF
@IsDir==TRUE RMDIR /S /Q @Path"`

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood your question correctly: you want to delete first level subfolders and all of their content only if they don't contain any files newer than X days. Is that correct? If so, you could do something like this:

```
mainfolder = "C:\main\folder"
maxAge     = 5 'days

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Function HasNewFiles(fldr)
  HasNewFiles = False

  For Each f In fldr.Files
    If DateDiff("d", f.DateLastModified, Now) < maxAge Then
      HasNewFiles = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  For Each sf In fldr.SubFolders
    HasNewFiles = HasNewFiles(sf)
    If HasNewFiles Then Exit Function
  Next
End Function

For Each subfldr In fso.GetFolder(mainfolder).SubFolders
  If Not HasNewFiles(subfldr) Then subfldr.Delete True
Next
```

Comment: This script does not appear to do anything.  I changed the mainfolder location to my temp folder.  I think its running but nothing gets removed.  I am not sure how to troubleshoot it either unfortunately.  Ill keep looking at it this morning.

Comment: @PY_ I had the two dates in the `DateDiff` statement reversed. Please try again.

Comment: Error Line 23 Char 31.  Object required: 'sf'

Comment: @PY_ *\*sigh\** Note to self: never re-use variables.